# c# dynamically modifying list

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I don't understand how to do it with foreach...
The goal is to modify a list each time we change Num.
Is the way with a Canvas List and a working List is ok for nice coding?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i_Num = 0;
        string Str_Num = "";
        string[] linkToPLC = {"toto[{0}].test{1}", "tata[{0}].test{1}", "titi[{0}].test{1}"};
        List<string> genlnkPLCCanvas = new List<string>(linkToPLC);
        List<string> genlnkPLCworkingwith = new List<string>(linkToPLC);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert Num: ");
        Str_Num = Console.ReadLine();
        i_Num = Convert.ToInt32(Str_Num);
        for (int item = 0; item < genlnkPLCCanvas.Count; item++)
        {
            genlnkPLCworkingwith[item] = String.Format(genlnkPLCworkingwith[item], i_Num, 200);
            Console.WriteLine("with List: result= " + genlnkPLCworkingwith[item]);
        }
        //foreach (string item in genlnkPLCCanvas) genlnkPLCworkingwith[item] = String.Format(item, i_Num, 200);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also String.Format doesn't print so you have to do `Console.WriteLine(String.Format(item, i_StationNum, 200);
)`

Comment: Wow, 4 answers later, still no answers tells the OP how to change strings in the list. All of them just tell how to print to the Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the existing list, you have to use `for` loop instead of `foreach` one:

```
 foreach (var item in list) ...
```

should be changed into

```
 for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i) {
   var item = list[i]; // not necessary, but often convenient
   ...
   list[i] = ... // modification
   ... 
 }
```

For instance

```
   for (int i = 0; i < genlnkPLCCanvas.Count; ++i) {
     var item = genlnkPLCCanvas[i];

     genlnkPLCCanvas[i] = string.Format(item, i_StationNum, 200);
   }
```

When testing try creating *reports* (put all the logic into the single readable query) and then printing them out in *one go*:

```
   ...

   var withListReport = genlnkPLC
     .Select(item => "with List: result = " + string.Format(item, i_StationNum, 200)); 

   var withoutListReport = genlnkPLC
     .Select(item => "without List: result = " + string.Format(item, i_StationNum, 200));

   // now you can do whatever you want with the reports: 
   //  - print them to console
   //      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Envrironment.NewLine, withListReport));
   //  - save to file: 
   //      File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt", withListReport);
   //  - print to, say, WinForm UI: 
   //      MyTextBox.Text = string.Join(Envrironment.NewLine, withListReport);

   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Envrironment.NewLine, withListReport));
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Envrironment.NewLine, withoutListReport));

   Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks M.Bychenko! I had my answers.

Answer (score 0):

No need to repeat foreach (the first one, did nothing to your item). Try this:

```
foreach (var item in genlnkPLC) 
    Console.WriteLine("with List: result= "+ String.Format(item, i_StationNum, 200));
```

Comment: You guess? We don't want guesses here. We want answers with reasoning.

Comment: i removed it @ThomasWeller. regards

Answer (score 0):

`String.Format()` returns a string, it doesn't change whatever you're formatting. Therefore, your first `foreach (var item in genlnkPLC)` creates temporary strings that are immediately destroyed.

```
foreach (var item in genlnkPLC) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("with List = " + String.Format(item, i_StationNum, 200));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
foreach (var item in genlnkPLC)
    Console.WriteLine("with List: result= "+item);
```

you are not using `String.Format` to insert arguments into the members of `genlnkPLC`, which are apparently intended as format strings. You can use

```
foreach (var item in genlnkPLC)
    Console.WriteLine("without List result = " + String.Format(item, i_StationNum, 200));
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't change the reference of the elements enumerated in a `foreach` loop. `string` is an inmutable object, so changing it replaces the old reference with a new one. If you want to change the elements in the list, you'll need to do it in a `for` loop, like this:

```
for (int item = 0; item < genlnkPLC.Count; item++)
            genlnkPLC[item]= String.Format(genlnkPLC[item], i_StationNum, 200);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess that the Canvas List and the working List is ok... I don't see other way to change the list withous erasing the {0} so it will work one time and then it will bugg. So I thought about a second list changed to work with it and a first list that doen's change and keep the {0}.

Answer (score 0):

As M.Bychenko says: "If you want to modify the existing list, you have to use for loop instead of foreach one:"

And thanks for the report tipp!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i_Num = 0;
        string Str_Num = "";
        string[] linkToPLC = {"toto[{0}].test{1}", "tata[{0}].test{1}", "titi[{0}].test{1}"};
        List<string> genlnkPLCCanvas = new List<string>(linkToPLC);
        List<string> genlnkPLCworkingwith = new List<string>(linkToPLC);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert Num: ");
        Str_Num = Console.ReadLine();
        i_Num = Convert.ToInt32(Str_Num);
        for (int item = 0; item < genlnkPLCCanvas.Count; item++)
        {
            genlnkPLCworkingwith[item] = String.Format(genlnkPLCCanvas[item], i_Num, 200);
        }
        var CanvasListReport = genlnkPLCCanvas.Select(item =>  "Canvas List = " + item);
        var WorkingListReport = genlnkPLCworkingwith.Select(item => "Working list = " + item);//string.Format(item, i_Num, 200));
        // now you can do whatever you want with the reports: 
        //  - print them to console
        //      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Envrironment.NewLine, withListReport));
        //  - save to file: File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt", withListReport);
        //  - print to, say, WinForm UI: 
        //      MyTextBox.Text = string.Join(Envrironment.NewLine, withListReport)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, CanvasListReport));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, WorkingListReport));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because

```
String.Format(item, i_StationNum, 200)
```

doesn't change the string in the list.

You have to assign the `String.Format` result to your item.